# IE 8 duplicates first element when printing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

I'm observing the following behavior when I use IE 8 to print a page from the webapp I'm working on.

`element n` is an html element.  The page is styled using a `media=print` sheet.

In ASCII:

```
+-----------------+
+ element 1       +
+ element 2       +
+ *page-break*    +
+ element 3       +
+ element 4       +
+-----------------+
```

prints

```
+-----------------+
+ element 1       +
+ element 2       +
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
+ element 3       +
+ element 4       +
+-----------------+
```

in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

IE prints:

```
+-----------------+
+ element 1       +
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
+ element 1       +
+ element 2       +
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
+ element 3       +
+ element 4       +
+-----------------+
```

The duplication of `element 1` has been documented so far as working when `element 1` is an `img` or an `h1` tag.  I have no idea if it works in further situations.

[Quick Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22internet+explorer%22+duplicate+first+element+print) didn't reveal anything of note.

Is this something others have encountered before?  <del>If not, I can post my code someplace.  Unfortunately, my work does a pretty good job of blocking anyplace that I could publish it.</del>  The code that is exhibiting the behavior when the first element is an `img` can be seen [at Pastie](http://pastie.org/1074910).  It's different CSS when the first element is an `h1` but the same concepts (I know it should be a single style… working on it).  If we can solve it for these styles I should be able to solve it for the others.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Can you post some markup and CSS to go with it (or link to working example)?

Comment: We need some code/markup because its not normal. Its not some normal behavior so something must be wrong in your code.

Comment: Markup posted for the `img` example.

Comment: Could anyone help me word this better to get an answer?  Seems like it should be a fairly simple bug to track down for a CSS guru…

Comment: I see no duplication when printing. From your demo I see a print preview of 6 pages. This is because you have `page-break-before: always;` in your demo code. Please post the problem code and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem happening to me. Not sure if this applies in your case, but I removed a `<thead></thead>` tag from the table and it stopped repeating that element. Just wanted to share as it was impossible to find an answer online anywhere.